# Symmetric operator : Is it $(\overline{T})^{*}= \overline{T^{*}}$ true?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, adjoint-operators

I have known that if the operator $T$ is closable, then
$$ T^{*}=(\overline{T})^{*}.$$

If the closure and dual can commutative? In other words, if $T$ is symmetric and unbounded, then
$$(\overline{T})^{*}=\overline{T^{*}}.$$

Is it true? 
Obviously, $T \subset T^{*}$, and $\overline{T} \subset \overline{T^{*}}$.

Moreover, is it true if T is essentially self-adjoint? ( If $T$ is self-adjoint, the proposition is true.)

Actually, I want to ask why it is true if $T$ is symmetric and essential self-adjoint 
$$ker(T^{*}+iI)=ker((\overline{T})^{*}+iI)?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $J$ is the isometric transpose map $J(x,y)=(y,-x)$ from $H\times H$ to itself, then
$$
       \mathcal{G}(T^*)= J\mathcal{G}(T)^{\perp}.
$$
This is well-defined if $T$ is densely-defined. The graph of the closure of $T$ is $\overline{\mathcal{G}(T)}$. Basic properties of orthogonal complement give
$$
      \mathcal{G}(T^*) = J\overline{\mathcal{G}(T)}^{\perp} = J\mathcal{G}(\overline{T})^{\perp} = \mathcal{G}(\overline{T}^*)$$

Answer (score 0):

$T^{\ast}$ is a closed operator, so $\overline{T^{\ast}}=T^{\ast}$. In general, we have $(\overline{T})^{\ast}\subseteq T^{\ast}$.

Comment: If $T$ is essentially self-adjoint, then $\overline{T}\subset T^{*}$. Is 
 the $T^{*}$ maximal closed extension?

Comment: The maximal closed extension is in the sense of?

Comment: There is a theorem saying that, if $T$ is a symmetric, then $T$ is essentially self-adjoint if and only if $T$ has exactly one self-adjoint extension.

Comment: If S is another closed extension of T, then $S=T^{*}$.

Comment: yes, I know this theorem that the self-adjoint extension of $T$.